# How to embed python-shell in a web page?

Tags: javascript, python

Recently I found [python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) a python interpreter. A simle implementation using `python-shell` is as follows:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
  // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
  console.log(message);
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

But since the `require` method is not applicable for web pages, how should it be embedded in the application?

Comment: This project is for nodejs, not for web pages. If you want to have python in browser you can try [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/)